# Is PhantomJS one process per browser instance just like Chrome or is it single process?

Tags: phantomjs

Google Chrome works in a single process per browser instance mode. This is a problem if the number of browser instances goes up to a very large number. I wish to do a lot of testing with PhantomJS with many browser instances and am worried about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is single process, just like node.js, and will never spawn something to process requests. Basically, everything is shared in the same instance (web pages, html ressources, ...)

You can spawn custom process, using execFile/spawn modules.

Comment: How is the browser single threaded or process, it has to render, so the browser would render in a different thread or process I guess and then come back to the NodeJS when an event happens? Or are you saying the rendering is all part of the NodeJS single process?